# can summation of n stochastic variable be a constant number?

Tags: stochastic-processes

Can we have a summation of $n$ stochastic variables equal to a constant? For example, I have $n$ normal variables which are the time for using different functions of the cell phone of one person. So the total using time is a constant, but the time for using different function is a stochastic variable.

Comment: Yes you can. Let $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_{n-1}$ be any random variables, and let $X_n=1-(X_1+X_2+\dots+X_{n-1})$. Then $X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n=1$ is constant. The situation you describe is a _degenerate_ multivariable normal distribution, to give you something to Google.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Can i have one more question. Suppose  X1,X2,…,Xn−1 is normal distribution, in that way, Xn=1−(X1+X2+⋯+Xn−1) is also normal distribution. Suppose Y1, Y2, ..., Yn are normal distribution. Does summation of Xi.Yi, i=1, 2, ..., n is normal distribution?  Thank you very much.

Comment: You should ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sum of independent random variables cannot be  a constant unless each of them is a constant. Without independence the sum can be a constant: take $X$ and $-X$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer